# Adding vertical swipe on ViewPager items to "dismiss" them

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I know that people who post no code and do not explain what they have done are not welcome here, but I think that the following question might really interest a lot of developers, and might worth trying to ask it.

I am using a classic ViewPager to display some informations in my application, and I have recently seen a great example in the planning poker application.

This is great and awesome, but what I really would like to achieve is a vertical swipe to remove a card in the ViewPager.

To be honnest, I have no place to start and even by reviewing the ViewPager source code, I feel a little bit lost.

Do you have any idea if someone already tried to acheve such a behaviour?

In case the answer is no, I will go on trying and post updates here, but as I have already wasted some hours, I fear that that will be hard.

[image]

Comment: have you got it done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and very easy as well. You just have to implement a gestureListner in you activity and then in the onFling() method track for the vertical swipe. Rest is all up to you implementation.

I am adding a little piece of code just to give you a starting point.

```
     private int swipe_Min_Distance = 200;
 private int swipe_Max_Distance = 600;
 private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
   float velocityY) {
if(xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
   return false;

  velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
  velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
        boolean result = false;

if(velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
   if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up swipe
   {
        //here you can do what ever you want after detection of your swipe
       }
   else{  //top to bottom swipe
    //here you can do what ever you want after detection of your swipe
       }

   result = true;
  }

   return result;
```

Comment: "rest" is the whole problem in this question.

Comment: in the onfling, just check the start and stop to decide whether it was vertical. then remove whatever you need

Comment: @IrfanUIHaq I think it's not the decision of the removal, but the movement of the views and animation after the fling has happened (to keep velocity).